# Detect multiple SMS receivers - Android

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I have developed a prototype for sending and receiving messages. I am able to get the receiver details such as the number and the message. The issue is that I want to detect multiple receivers(more than 1). Now one way to do is check if the message is an MMS but the issue is that if the message contains any media then that is an MMS too. how do i fix this problem.For us the number of digits is 10 but may vary from country to country. I want to make it generic.

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //---get the SMS message passed in---

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";       
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];   
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, true);
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       // notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    }           
}
```

I want to check if the received message is an MMS or SMS. How can I do that ?

Comment: This is a broad question - The only way an SMS has multiple recipients though I assume if it is an MMS. So check if it's an MMS first and then check the number of recipients. If that's > 1 than you have multiple recipients...

Comment: How do i check if number of receipients > 1

Comment: @Rohit_Ramhumar Through your prototype? We have no way of knowing what your doing unless you post code.